# How to pass a reference to a value inside a dictionary?

Tags: python

Suppose we have a dictionary:

```
some_dict = {
    "first": 11111,
    "second": {
        "second_1": 22222,
        "second_2": 232323,
        "second_3": 99999
    }
}
```

if I create a new variable a with value `some_dict["second"]`, then it will be a reference:

```
ref = some_dict["second"]
```

Accordingly, if I change the value of the nested dictionary `second` in `some_dict`, then it will also change in `ref`:

```
some_dict["second"]["second_1"] = "not a second_1"
print(ref)
```

Output:

```
{'second_1': 'not a second_1', 'second_2': 232323, 'second_3': 99999}
```

How can I create the same reference, but not to a nested dictionary, but to a value, such as `int` or `str`?

Like this:

```
ref = some_dict["second"]["second_1"]

some_dict["second"]["second_1"] = "not a second_1"
print(ref)
```

Estimated output:

```
not a second_1
```

Comment: It's not possible. Python has references to containers, but not to values.

Comment: "How can I create the same reference, but not to a nested dictionary, but to a value, such as int or str?" In the same way. It just doesn't help you write the code that you want. `ref = some_dict["second"]["second_1"]` creates a "reference" to the integer. But `some_dict["second"]["second_1"] =` modifies the inner dict; it **does not modify** the integer. You cannot, in fact, modify that integer, as there are no methods that do so. Assignment never modifies the pre-existing assigned value (if any).

Comment: Please also see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html.

Answer (score 0):

The quick-and-dirty answer is to put it into a one-element list.

```
my_original_int = [0]
my_ref_to_int = my_original_int
```

Now modifications to (the integer value inside) either variable will reflect in the other.

**But**, that's horrible coding practice. At minimum, that should be encapsulated into a class.

```
class Cell:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

my_original_int = Cell(0)
my_ref_to_int = my_original_int
```

Then either can be accessed or modified through the `.value` member.

Even better would be to make a specific class to your use case. Ask yourself *why* you're wanting to alias integers. "My integer represents data in a JSON file somewhere" is a great answer, and it suggests that there should be a `MyJsonData` class somewhere that has integer fields, and you should be passing around references to *that* instead of to the integers.

Basically, make your data usage as explicit as possible, and your code will be more readable and intuitive. I even go so far as to try to avoid aliasing lists and dictionaries. If I find myself needing such behavior, it's often about time for me to encapsulate that list in a class with a more specific name and detailed docstring.